# Word/Excel 2010 import defaults to 365

Tags: office365, excel-2010, word-2010

I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find a solution.

I have a very odd issue...

**Background:**

I got a new Laptop that already has the Trial of everything.
My Office 365 Trial has ended and do not have the available funds to purchase it at this time.
I Still have an Original of Office 2010 which I have installed.

**My Issue / Question:**

When I try to import an Excel Spreadsheet into Word, it keeps on trying to insert the 365 version off Excel, which then wants me to register / Purchase.

How can I get around this so it inserts an Excel 2010 Spreadsheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the solution...

Everyone says that you must uninstall 365... This did not work for me, nor did uninstalling and reinstalling Office 2010.

The Solution for me was to Delete my Inactive 365 Account.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install 2010? Did you install 2010 over a running 365? (I don't know whether that is possible, you are asked by installer to first uninstall 365)

Even after uninstalling, there could be traces of 365 in your system that hint to word that you are on 365.

There is a Microsoft tool to erase MS Office fully, that a normal uninstall through Programs and Files can't achieve. Download and run that tool to get your box complete free of all MS Office, and then reinstall 2010 afresh.

Comment: Thank you, I did use that tool already before asking here, but it did not work. I did figure out the solution by removing my 365 Account.